# How to split the list into sublist in python

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools, date-range

Hey Experts i know my question is really basic and common for which there is lots of answer available on net but i'm kind of stuck with my own condition which i have applied please help me write a correct condition to get the sublist In the below code i have a date range where i'm getting all the months name between the date range from which i'm splitting the list of all the months name and length_to_split list **code:**

```
import pandas as pd

date1 = "2012-06-06 00:00:00"  # input start date
date2 = "2015-03-02 00:00:00"
newList=[]
length_to_split=[]
count = 0
for i in pd.date_range(start=date1, end=date2, freq='MS'):
    d=i.strftime("%b")
    count += 1
    if 'Dec' == d:
        length_to_split.append(count)
        count = 0

    newList.append(d)

print("newList-",newList)
print("length_to_split"-length_to_split)
```

this will print:

```
newList- ['Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
length_to_split- [6, 12, 12]
```

but you can see the "length_to_split" which is only have 3 length i want the last 3 months('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar') count too in my length_to_split which will look like this **Expected output should be-length_to_split- [6, 12, 12, 3]** 
so i can get the sublist using that so for that i have a code like this:

```
from itertools import islice

# Input list initialization
Input = newList

# list of length in which we have to split

# Using islice
Inputt = iter(Input)
Output = [list(islice(Inputt, elem))
          for elem in length_to_split]

# Printing Output
print("Initial list is:", Input)
print("Split length list: ", length_to_split)
print("List after splitting", Output)
```

i know my condition is not correct which i have written like this :

```
if 'Dec' == d:
    length_to_split.append(count)
    count = 0
```

it will only match when it will find the Dec i want to get the count after words also please help me any help will me appreciable thanks in advance

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani you can see on the basis of condition its getting only length_to_split- [6, 12, 12] but at last there is 3 months which ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar') after the Dec is left i want to add count to the final length which will become length_to_split- [6, 12, 12, 3]

Comment: @snehilsingh you don't need this? you can split on 6, 12 and 12 and you are left with the last 3?

Comment: you can try: len(newList) - (6 + 12 + 12)

Comment: @Chrisvdberge yea correct this program will give sublist but i want to create a sublist of months on the basis of jan-dec if some month don't have till dec then that list contain only that months

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is the [6, 12, 12, 3] list in the end, there is a simpler solution:

```py
dates = [d.year for d in pd.date_range(date1, date2, freq='MS')]
counter=collections.Counter(dates)

print(counter) # Counter({2012: 6, 2013: 12, 2014: 12, 2015: 3})
print(list(counter.values())) # [6, 12, 12, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
sum = reduce((lambda x, y: x + y), length_to_split)
length_to_split.append(len(newList) - sum)
print(length_to_split)
```

If you are using `python 3` then import reduce from `functools` :

```
from functools import reduce
```

Comment: can you please explain this

Comment: I have modified as per my comment in question section. `len(newList) - (6 + 12 + 12)` Addition of list is doing by `reduce` functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can use an else with the for loop and append the count to the length_to_split at the end of the loop if it is greater than or equals 1.

```
import pandas as pd

date1 = "2012-06-06 00:00:00"  # input start date
date2 = "2015-03-02 00:00:00"
newList=[]
length_to_split=[]
count = 0
for i in pd.date_range(start=date1, end=date2, freq='MS'):
    d=i.strftime("%b")
    count += 1
    if 'Dec' == d:
        length_to_split.append(count)
        count = 0

    newList.append(d)
else:
    if count > 0:
        length_to_split.append(count)

print("newList-",newList)
print("length_to_split"-length_to_split)
```

**length_to_split** should now be **[6, 12, 12, 3]**

Answer (score 0):

> We can use last year as a flag point and check when it changes. This
>   change point signals to write down the counted months. And at last we
>   check if last counted months are 12 or no and if not we write it down
>   also

```
import pandas as pd

date1 = "2012-06-06 00:00:00"  # input start date
date2 = "2015-03-02 00:00:00"
newList = []
length_to_split = []
count = 0
flag = True
last_year = -1  # to emphasis that we should select a number completely out of acceptable year number
for i in pd.date_range(start=date1, end=date2, freq='MS'):
    count += 1
    year = int(i.strftime("%Y"))

    if last_year == -1:
        last_year = year

    if last_year == year - 1:
        last_year = year
        length_to_split.append(count-1)
        count = 1

if count > 1:
    length_to_split.append(count)

print("newList-", newList)
print("length_to_split-", length_to_split)
```